# Slow Select query execution on Date column

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I did a migration from a SQL CE database to a SQLite database (3.18.0) but I'm having a slow query when there are datetime columns in the Select.

My SQLite column that stores the Datetime is of type INTEGER. Dates are stored in UNIX epoch (seconds).

On a table with 15 columns with 1000 records, my query is about 3 seconds.
The same query without the date (only name) is instantaneous.

```
SELECT Name,
CreatedDate    
FROM [Table]
```

Is there anything special to door do I have to store dates in Text ?

EDIT:

From Entity framework, the generated query is :

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[VisualizationIndex] AS [VisualizationIndex], 
[Extent1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
[Extent1].[IdentifierParent] AS [IdentifierParent], 
[Extent1].[IdentifierEnvironment] AS [IdentifierEnvironment], 
[Extent1].[IdentifierReference] AS [IdentifierReference], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
[Extent1].[Visibility] AS [Visibility], 
[Extent1].[Layer] AS [Layer], 
[Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
[Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Extent1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified]
FROM [CV_UsersComponents] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Name] ASC

-- Executing at 10/31/2017 4:52:47 PM +01:00
-- Completed in 3433 ms with result: SQLiteDataReader
```

Comment: Is it still slow if you SELECT the date column, but do not actually read it in your code?

Comment: I'm doing the select in Visual Studio with SQLite/SQL Server Compact toolbox from ErikEJ, so maybe there is something that slows down.

Comment: And it's slow using SQLite with entity framework 6 too.

Comment: Show the actual code.

Comment: My question is edited with the generated query

Comment: This is not related to Entity Framework, it doesn't matter that EF generated the SQL that runs slow on itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where the performance problem comes from.
In SQLite the column order is very important !

I moved "created" and "lastModified" columns before a column of type TEXT which stores some XML data.

Then my query is now instantaneous.
More info here :
http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Does-column-order-matter-for-performance-td81880.html